# Xamarin android webview open dialog for choosing camera or file manager

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to open a dialog for chosing files or take a photo in a webview when clicking on a input on the website. When clicking on the input now it opens the filemanager.
I used this page for testing it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture
my input looks like this `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">`
it works when using chrome in android.

Answer (score 1):

You can set  **settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true** in android webview renderer to enable js  like:

```
public class Mywebview : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public Mywebview(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {

                Android.Webkit.WebView webview = (Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
                WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
                settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: where do i put that code? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: iI found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/357886/camera-not-showing-in-webview-on-the-andriod.html

Comment: But this line         File imageStorageDir = new File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "MyAppFolder"); i get an error when trying to build and run. i tried adding using Java.IO; but that gives me the error "com.google.android.material.tabs.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity does not exsist"

Comment: you can refer to here to know how to use custom renderer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview